# How can I read multiple .mat files from 5 different folders which are stored in my main folder

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, data-analysis

I have one folder containing 5 different folders (each has 10 `.mat` files) and I want to load or read all files in MATLAB. Can you give me some hint or some helpful info how can i do that?

Each `.mat` file contains 30000x6 matrix and I also need to store one column vector from each files and save it in one separate matrix.
I need this matrix for PCA.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are they .m files or .mat files?  Usually .m holds code and .mat holds data, but you're saying you have .m with data.

Comment: @Brick Ya sorry they are .mat files. all files contains lots of reading. and they stored in one 3000*6 matrix.

Comment: @Brick ya they are .mat files

Comment: **Please**, bold **text** makes **the** text very **annoying** to **read**. I **removed it,** make a rollback if you prefer the original format.

Comment: So what's wrong with calling `load` on each file?

Answer (score -1):

In first place, you need to discover folders inside your main folder (let's assume it is named `main_folder`). You can do that using `dir` command, which returns a structure with several interesting features:

```
dirContents = dir('main_folder')
```

Outputs

```
dirContents = 

9x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

Loop over result looking for entries with `isdir` field set to 1 (be careful with `.` and `..`). If you also want to search in nested folders, apply this procesure recursively.

For each entry, get files with desired extension. You can use `dir` again with wildcards:

```
% Loop over the directories inside 'main_folder'
for indDir = 1:numel(dirContents)
    thisEntry = dirContents{indDir};
    if thisEntry.isdir
        % If entry is a directory, search .mat files
        matFilesInFolder = dir(['main_folder/',thisEntry.name,'/*.mat']);
        % For each found .mat file, load contents
        for indMat = 1:numel(matFilesInFolder)
            thisMat = matFilesInFolder{indMat};
            matContents = load(['main_folder/',thisEntry.name,'/',thisMat.name]);

            % HERE DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE
        end
    end
end
```

This is the difficult part. Code has not been tested, it might need fixes.

I am not sure what you need to do with data. Check how contents are loaded and process them according to your needs.

Comment: Any comment why this solution deserves a negative vote? It answers the question AFAIK :-(

Comment: _"Code has not been tested, it might need fixes"_, manual concatenation instead of using `fullfile`, OP is going to be in tears when he finds that copypasting your code won't fulfil his _"need to store one column vector from each files and save it in one separate matrix"_

Comment: Didn't know about `fullfile`, thanks. Anyway, I don't think that the goal of stackoverflow is getting code ready to paste in your project, that's why I prefer to provide not deeply tested code to beginners :-)